# Constraining output to not be undefined if input parameter is definitely not undefined

Tags: typescript

I have a function like

```
const toString = (date?: Date) => date?.toString();
```

Which I would like typecheck to `(Date) => string` when given a `Date` but to `(Date | undefined) => string | undefined` when given `Date | undefined` or undefined.

I have tried something like this in a number of different ways:

```
type Verify<T, D> = T extends undefined ? D | undefined : D;

const dateToString = <T extends Date | undefined>(date: Verify<T, Date>) => {
    if (date === undefined) {
        return undefined as Verify<T, string>;
    }
    return date.toString() as Verify<T, string>;
};

const a = dateToString(new Date(23));
const b = dateToString(undefined as Date | undefined);
const c = dateToString(undefined);
```

But I cannot seem to get the behavior I want, either everything typechecks to `(Date | undefined) => string` or `(Date) => string`. Apparently I do not grok typescript generics with constraints.

A proper name for this helper constraining type would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```js
type Verify<T, D> = T extends undefined ? D | undefined : D;

const dateToString = <T extends Date | undefined>(date: T): Verify<T, string> => {
    if (date === undefined) {
        return undefined as Verify<T, string>;
    }
    return date.toString();
};

const a = dateToString(new Date());                    // const a: string
const b = dateToString(undefined as Date | undefined); // const b: string | undefined
const c = dateToString(undefined);                     // const c: string | undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using a [function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)...

```
function dateToString(date: Date): string;
function dateToString(date?: Date): string | undefined ;
function dateToString(date?: Date): string | undefined {
    if (date === undefined) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return date.toString();
}

const x = dateToString(new Date()); // x: string
const y = dateToString();           // y: string | undefined
```